# iPhone crash log - help me understand it

Tags: iphone, crash

Apple has sent me 3 crash logs, but I didn't undestand what is wrong. Please help me:

> We found that your app crashed on iPad 2 running iOS 5.0.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app crashed when a section is selected.

1-

```
    Incident Identifier: B40D3CDD-A3AF-4914-95D2-5D5D4C292BA1
CrashReporter Key:   fa143bf5503fbd1d873fe2c57e86620af832f301
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:         Top 3500 Words [866]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/791ABCC5-1649-4E1F-85F0-0CFE8B2C8DB0/Top 3500 Words.app/Top 3500 Words
Identifier:      Top 3500 Words
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-01-03 13:45:58.041 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbf800008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3556cfbc objc_msgSend + 16
1   Top 3500 Words                  0x000fdbe8 0xee000 + 64488
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3556e0be _objc_rootRelease + 30
3   UIKit                           0x32742f40 -[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:] + 1464
4   UIKit                           0x326e2934 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 140
5   UIKit                           0x326e27b8 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 896
6   UIKit                           0x3265c814 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 464
7   UIKit                           0x32661fb2 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 46
8   QuartzCore                      0x33ee5ba0 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 196
9   QuartzCore                      0x33f7b402 CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks_compat(double, void*) + 78
10  QuartzCore                      0x33ee54c4 _ZN2CAL14timer_callbackEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPv + 140
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3412ba5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3412b6c2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 358
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3412a298 __CFRunLoopRun + 1200
14  CoreFoundation                  0x340ad4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
15  CoreFoundation                  0x340ad39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
16  GraphicsServices                0x30998fc6 GSEventRunModal + 150
17  UIKit                           0x3267573c UIApplicationMain + 1084
18  Top 3500 Words                  0x000efc0a 0xee000 + 7178
19  Top 3500 Words                  0x000efbd4 0xee000 + 7124

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36bbe3b4 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x33154f74 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x33154c92 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36bcecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cf430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cf409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36bbe010 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36bbe206 mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3412b41c __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3412a154 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x340ad4d6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x340ad39e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x335de128 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cf9c16 _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cf9ad0 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x36bcecd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cf430a _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32cf409c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x1120efc0    r1: 0x36f3d09c      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x000000b0
    r4: 0xbf800000    r5: 0x36f3d09c      r6: 0x0022a190      r7: 0x2feebc6c
    r8: 0x0022a190    r9: 0x0dbcf427     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0x0024d610
    ip: 0x3ed3f328    sp: 0x2feebc54      lr: 0x000fdbef      pc: 0x3556cfbc
  cpsr: 0x000f0030

Binary Images:
   0xee000 -   0x103fff +Top 3500 Words armv7  <b0c7b594f6fb3bbd945c57da0cce4354> /var/mobile/Applications/791ABCC5-1649-4E1F-85F0-0CFE8B2C8DB0/Top 3500 Words.app/Top 3500 Words
0x2feed000 - 0x2ff0ed57  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x303ae000 - 0x303baff0  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x303bb000 - 0x303fbffd  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x303fc000 - 0x3047bffd  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x304b2000 - 0x3066efff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x307c9000 - 0x307c9fff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x307d6000 - 0x307ddfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x307e2000 - 0x307f1fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x307f8000 - 0x30955ffe  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x30980000 - 0x30991fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30992000 - 0x30994ffe  MobileInstallation armv7  <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x30995000 - 0x309a0fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30aae000 - 0x30ab4fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30af4000 - 0x30af4fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30af5000 - 0x30b58ffb  IMCore armv7  <c235020b86123e95820f7323916023aa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x30c4e000 - 0x30cf8fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x30cf9000 - 0x30d29ffe  ContentIndex armv7  <e610e7e8c8653d728dcc3c8fb471a994> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x30d44000 - 0x30d79fff  DataAccess armv7  <432578d415dd3398b3487f003b3100ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x30d7c000 - 0x30dbffff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x30dc0000 - 0x30de3ff7  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x30f70000 - 0x30f77ff7  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x30f86000 - 0x30f9dfff  WebBookmarks armv7  <ca6cb19e568738a0a6e30b616ee33ab0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x30fb0000 - 0x30fb1ffe  DataMigration armv7  <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30fb2000 - 0x3108cff6  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x311cd000 - 0x311eaff7  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x31224000 - 0x3147eff7  MediaToolbox armv7  <ab91ec33f2b23606bd0443163beff710> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x31491000 - 0x31497fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31564000 - 0x31564ffe  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3156c000 - 0x3157bff7  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x316ef000 - 0x31700ff3  libxpc.dylib armv7  <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x31701000 - 0x317adff6  MediaControlSender armv7  <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x317ae000 - 0x317b1ff8  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x317b2000 - 0x317fdffe  CoreLocation armv7  <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x319f8000 - 0x319fffff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31b35000 - 0x31b55fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x31b64000 - 0x31bfcfff  EventKit armv7  <f340aafa660d308a8cd86fd180aeaad9> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x31ce4000 - 0x31d20ff7  iCalendar armv7  <59d80290d8733df8a6310da65b497fc9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31d27000 - 0x31d2bfff  FTClientServices armv7  <8f823e791c9e37b4b47323bb0286e86c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x31d94000 - 0x31d9fff7  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31da0000 - 0x31dafffc  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <09c637a85e3d3af488e59ced95a5a916> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32644000 - 0x32addfff  UIKit armv7  <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32b18000 - 0x32c96fff  Foundation armv7  <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32cd4000 - 0x32ce9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32cea000 - 0x32d77ff3  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x32d81000 - 0x32dcaff9  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32f1e000 - 0x32fccffb  Message armv7  <0d844e0108b1301bb08a74df3e3589b5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x32fe1000 - 0x33004ffd  MobileSync armv7  <be06df250fff368b92bc0a1defc6df9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x33005000 - 0x33009fff  CertUI armv7  <9d24f62513913888b2ac55f1db27b908> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x33107000 - 0x33150ff3  AddressBook armv7  <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x33151000 - 0x33167fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x331b3000 - 0x331b6ffe  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x331b7000 - 0x331b9ffd  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x3328e000 - 0x33296ffe  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33297000 - 0x332bcff9  OpenCL armv7  <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x33360000 - 0x33383ff7  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x33536000 - 0x33cedffb  WebCore armv7  <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x33d3b000 - 0x33d6efff  MIME armv7  <0c29ae0826c53ebbaf9424b389016b68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x33d6f000 - 0x33d82fff  Notes armv7  <b2cb7346cb2b36eca53d22534c53b508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x33dfa000 - 0x33dfdfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x33dfe000 - 0x33e02ffd  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x33e03000 - 0x33eb0ff7  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x33eba000 - 0x33faaff3  QuartzCore armv7  <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33fab000 - 0x33facffd  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3407b000 - 0x34085ff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3409e000 - 0x341b5ff9  CoreFoundation armv7  <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x341b6000 - 0x341c0ffb  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x341c5000 - 0x341d9ffb  PersistentConnection armv7  <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x341da000 - 0x341f0ff7  DictionaryServices armv7  <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x34719000 - 0x3471afff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x34764000 - 0x34769ffe  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <c3062554536438f9874c88363df7f60b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3483c000 - 0x34849ff7  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3485b000 - 0x3485fffc  libcache.dylib armv7  <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34860000 - 0x34866ffe  MobileKeyBag armv7  <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3486e000 - 0x34b2ffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34b30000 - 0x34b34ffe  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34b37000 - 0x34b46ff2  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34b5e000 - 0x34b61fff  ActorKit armv7  <8c167170891238b3940f9f54105b6eb9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x34b67000 - 0x34ba4fff  FTServices armv7  <fc9e7d223d3f33898603cfba115f5094> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x34cb2000 - 0x34cb8fff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x34ccd000 - 0x34d09ff7  AppSupport armv7  <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34d14000 - 0x34d18fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34d2f000 - 0x35273ff5  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3527f000 - 0x35280fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35285000 - 0x35285fff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x352aa000 - 0x352f4ff3  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x352f5000 - 0x352f6fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x35340000 - 0x35391ff6  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x353db000 - 0x354abffc  WebKit armv7  <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x354ae000 - 0x354e9ff7  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x354ee000 - 0x354f7fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x354f8000 - 0x35568ff6  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x35569000 - 0x3562fd43  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x35630000 - 0x35636ff3  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x35637000 - 0x3569bffb  MessageUI armv7  <c9d526c181ed3625b32327044d78dad3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x356a9000 - 0x356f2ff0  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35ab6000 - 0x35b2ffff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35b30000 - 0x35b6fff3  QuickLook armv7  <fdc0e38e19f9316fb0923c390e8d3ccd> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x35c68000 - 0x35c94fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <f0eca72c10c537fa89b17fd97e003faf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x35da9000 - 0x35da9fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x35dfa000 - 0x35e31fff  Security armv7  <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x35e32000 - 0x35e6bffb  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x35e6c000 - 0x35fb1fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x35fb2000 - 0x3614a60f  CoreData armv7  <dd6d139d99e5309f9df33f7b6a044b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x36186000 - 0x3618bffc  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x361be000 - 0x36241ffc  CoreMotion armv7  <f4365ff3974b3049b3f04b3f55a46ae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x36244000 - 0x36249ffe  ApplePushService armv7  <2e620a6e8ee8387ba2771cfd7870c90e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x36315000 - 0x3634aff7  SystemConfiguration armv7  <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3634b000 - 0x363f1fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <d785fe33cd263f5aba861ad919c66924> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x363f2000 - 0x363f3fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3641b000 - 0x3643afff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x3643b000 - 0x36529ffa  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3652a000 - 0x36540ff3  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x36549000 - 0x36555fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x365ba000 - 0x365bdffd  libmacho.dylib armv7  <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x365c1000 - 0x365daff7  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x365df000 - 0x365e3ffe  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36722000 - 0x3677dfff  StoreServices armv7  <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x3677e000 - 0x367c3fff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x368ad000 - 0x368b0ffc  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x368b3000 - 0x36904fff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x36b77000 - 0x36bbbffb  MobileCoreServices armv7  <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36bbd000 - 0x36bd3ffd  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x36bfd000 - 0x36bfefff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36c2d000 - 0x36f9effb  TextInput armv7  <64d1227219b03c51ba4854ec2f79c335> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x370bb000 - 0x370c2fff  MailServices armv7  <a5e048e513b237b78d62fb3996a85fa9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x370df000 - 0x37128ffa  CoreMedia armv7  <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3748e000 - 0x3766bff7  AudioToolbox armv7  <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3767a000 - 0x37690ff5  EAP8021X armv7  <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3769b000 - 0x376a7fff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x376a8000 - 0x376a8fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x377d7000 - 0x378aeff1  CFNetwork armv7  <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x378d4000 - 0x37a1dff1  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37b2e000 - 0x37b78fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x37b79000 - 0x37bb6fff  IOKit armv7  <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x37c2f000 - 0x37d53ff3  JavaScriptCore armv7  <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x37ec0000 - 0x37f89fff  Celestial armv7  <c18e76311fc33016be930da83050b96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x37f96000 - 0x37f9bff7  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x37f9c000 - 0x37fa0ffd  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x37fe6000 - 0x38022fff  IMFoundation armv7  <d93ec1a0f854355da1e4f8aca176e749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x38023000 - 0x3807afff  CoreAudio armv7  <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x38087000 - 0x3808bfff  Marco armv7  <526949ce76323de09ee69812383c2953> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3808c000 - 0x380b5ff7  AppleAccount armv7  <b0baa956f6a8308a8d9faac126ef6f95> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x380dc000 - 0x380dcffd  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
```